# Where does Ubuntu Touch emulator store drives?

Tags: qemu, ubuntu-emulator

I installed the `ubuntu-emulator` package. I created an instance. I didn't remove it before uninstalling the package but now the instance isn't listed when I type `ubuntu-emulator list`. So where does the emulator store the virtual drives?

Answer (score 2):

I found it myself with `sudo find / -name "*.img"`. They are stored in `$HOME/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator`

Well, it was also mentioned here.

```
$ sudo ubuntu-emulator destroy Nexus5
Are you sure you want to remove instance 'Nexus5' located in /home/marten/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/Nexus5?
[y/n]
```